# Programmatically create Google Workspace web SAML app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

Is it possible to create a Google Workspace SAML app programmatically? If yes, would appreciate an example of such script.

I have looked up google workspace documentation and postings on a relevant group.
I would expect an answer if it is possible or not at this point, and if yes, then a pointer to such script.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per answer from Google Workspace support, it is impossible - "... at this moment there is no possibility to create a Google Workspace SAML app programmatically and there is no example of such a script available."